# Change color and back button title of Navigation Bar from Swift 3 code

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swift3, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Making UI of my app using code only. 
Can't find how customize couple elements:
1. Button 'Back' now it looks like:

[image]

and it should looks like:

[image]

So, how I can get rid of 'Back' text from button title, keeping '<' system icon there? And how I can change colors of back button and title of navigation bar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks! How get rid of text "Back" from button title?

Comment: @zzheads Inside of viewDidLoad, you'd have to simple call...

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: "your_image_name", style: .normal, target: self, action: #selector(handleBack))

You'd then have to create a function called "func handleBack" and inside this, simply call this to dismiss the view just like a back button would:

dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    //any other initial stuffs

    //for the bar
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    //for the button
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.titleView?.tintColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction from your xcode. You can do this easily. I also marked on the image . Select 1. Select the Standard Editor, 2. Show the File inspector 3 Set global Ting

[image: From your Xcode you can do this]

Answer (score 0):

With XCode 12.3 can change the Title Color and Back Button using the following.

[image: Change Title Color]

[image: Change Back Button Color]